# Can I fail my Maven build based on an existing Karma coverage report?

Tags: maven, karma-coverage, maven-cobertura-plugin

I use Maven to build a multi-component project. One of the components is a web app with HTML and JavaScript. Maven invokes NPM and Karma to run that component's unit and integration tests, written in QUnit. This yields two independent Cobertura coverage reports that I then combine into one with istanbul-combine.

As a final step, I'd like the Maven build to fail if that combined Cobertura report doesn't satisfy my coverage requirements. But how?

I've tried the [Cobertura Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/), but it seems to be unfit to simply read an existing report and apply its `check` configuration. First, it needlessly repeats the build's tests (["Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase `test` prior to executing itself."](http://www.mojohaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html)), then it finds that it cannot instrument the non-Java resources, then it simply stops, without any log output whatsoever.

Are there other plugins that fit? Could changing the report format help? (Doesn't have to be Cobertura.)